# Django Many to many how to give input to 3rd table

Tags: django

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
  
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    In [5]: Author.objects.all()
Out[5]: <QuerySet [<Author: Shanmukh>, <Author: Shyam>, <Author: sai>, <Author: VICKYS>, <Author: Himayu>, <Author: Himanya>, <Author: Srinivas>, <Author: LASKARATOYIBA>, <Author: ISI>, <Author: JAMI>]>
```

please help in solving this i dont understand how do i give data to 3rd table which is a combination of id bookid and authorid

Comment: what third table you mean, is it intermediate table??

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to add an Author to a Book. You can use this:

```
book.authors.add(author)
```

See this in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#:%7E:text=%3E%3E%3E%20a2%20%3D%20Article(headline%3D%27NASA%20uses%20Python%27)%0A%3E%3E%3E%20a2.save()%0A%3E%3E%3E%20a2.publications.add(p1%2C%20p2)%0A%3E%3E%3E%20a2.publications.add(p3):%7E:text=Create%20another%20Article%2C%20and%20set%20it%20to%20appear%20in%20the%20Publications%3A)